# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

Directly I have installed Wordpress in Live server. I can able to login within wordpress. But while I try to click it on "setting" in installed plugin It is redirecting to the error page, which shows "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page".

I read more article regarding this issue. All says, check out database name, wp_capabilities. I have checked. It also fine to me.

[image: PHP MyAdmin Page]

Please help to me solve my problem.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Check below solutions:-

**In your DB,**

```
wp_capabilities should be a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

wp_user_level should be 10
```

If not working then check,

```
// ** MySQL settings ** //
define('DB_NAME', 'madeupname');     // The name of the database
define('DB_USER', 'madeupuser');     // Your MySQL username
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'madeuppw'); // ...and password
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.yoursite.com');     // ...and the server MySQL is running on
// Change the prefix if you want to have multiple blogs in a single database.
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';   // example: 'wp_' or 'b2' or 'mylogin_'
```

Check this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page) also.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks Ravi. But I have checked all above configuration. It is perfect to me. Even I am facing same problem.

Comment: Have you checked link? Link has lots of useful suggestions.

Comment: Ya i did force-upgrade.php & checked wp_config, wp_user nothing is working to me.